# Codeigniter Passing parameters from view to controller

Tags: codeigniter, anchor, parameter-passing

view has this anchor:

```
echo anchor('login', 'Login or Register');
```

how do i send the current url to my controller login? and then use it on another function called login_validation?

all i want is, login and back to the last url, however nothing works. so i thought saving the current url when i click "Login or Register" and then after login, on function login_validation, i should redirect to that url saved...

controller index

```
public function index(){

    $this->main_login();

}
```

main_login

```
public function main_login(){

        $this->load->helper('url');
        // on view i will call the next function login_validation
        $this->load->view("view_login");

}
```

login_validation

```
public function login_validation(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    (...)

    if ($this->form_validation->run()){

            // i should redirect the saved url here, instead of home
            redirect('home');

     }else{
        (...)
     }



  }
```

i appreciate any help

Comment: put it on the view as a hidden input in a form you submit, or use the server array for http referer

Comment: hmm, i will check that now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by using `$this->agent->referrer()` in your controller class `main_login()`.

Save the referrer url into your session, and once the user is validated (or *if* they are), then you pull that string from session:

in main_login():

```
// grabs url where you clicked login
$this->session->set_userdata('referrer_url', $this->agent->referrer());
```

in login_validation():

```
// pull url from session and redirect, make sure to account for not having url too
redirect( $referrer_url );
```

Comment: i was having some errors, about referrer not declared, and couldnt use it inside login_validation, so i made a function geturl(), which loads library user_agent and returns $this->session->set_userdata('referrer_url', $this->agent->referrer()); and then i called it on main_login and used again on login_validation... but it returns to my main page, and not the last one… its because the changes i have made to get your code work?

Comment: you need to capture the referrer before you redirect *anywhere*, so if you are redirecting from index -> main_login() you need to capture @ index. Try adding an exit condition and testing your referrer. Also my code for login_validation is not complete, so don't assume $referrer_url is the session, I'm just outlining what you need to do. Call the session var.

Comment: so was this a solution? If so mark it as such otherwise post an update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the delay, i was really busy with the end of the semester,

So i will explain how i did to solve this problem, all i wanted was back to the current page after the login.. so, everytime i open my view login i will save the last page url, with this code:

```
$refering_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '' ;
```

and then i should save it in my session, so i can access from my controller and redirect the user to the last page, but look, i can’t simple save the url every time i access the view login, beucase every time i miss the password, i will be redirected to the login page, and so the last url, will the login and not the last one, and of course its wrong, So we have to save it on session, but only in the first time we access the view login, to do that, i compare the variable above ($refering_url) to the view login and view login validation, if its not the same, i can confirm that the previous page is the one i was before the login, and then i can save it to my session,

here the comparison, and the last url saved in my session:

```
if (($refering_url != ‘URL TO VIEW LOGIN‘) && 
    ($refering_url != ‘URL TO LOGIN VALIDATION){

        $this->session->set_userdata('url', $refering_url);

    }
```

after login is validated, on the controller, i should redirect the user , to the last page he was (the url saved on the session), to do that i used this code:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
$url=$this->session->userdata('url');
redirect($url, 'refresh');
```